# "expected NUMBER got binary" exception occurred during data retrieval

Tags: java, hibernate, null, named-query, param

Below is the Entity class

```
Node {
    Long id; 
    Node parentId;
}
```

hibernate named query using :

```
select n from  Node n where n.parentId.id = :id
```

param value passing   is  null , i mean "id"  passing is null

and getting the exception

```
" Expected NUMBER got BINARY "
```

Can any one suggest please how to overcome this exception .

i tried different checks for :id  in that named query , still getting the same exception ,  i saw in the blogs , they all mentioning , when the exception will occur , but no suggestions to overcome this exception

Comment: Can you please insert the method which invokes this NamedQuery? ...just to see the whole pic.

Comment: hibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(queryName,
                paramNames, paramValues);

here hibernateTemplate , is the utility proided by spring ,

queryName is defined as a names query in the xml and that query as mentioned above 

select n from  Node n where n.parentId.id = :id

paramNames  =  "nodeId"


paramValues  = null

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a non existing parameter (*nodeId*). Change the parameter name to **id**.

```
hibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("Node.findById", "id", null);
```

Good luck, 
Gergely

Comment: their is no such non existing parameter referred in the query , i am using the following parameters 
n.parentId.id  and value :id which is passed via the query